# как сделать поиск по дате с помощью выбора даты в календаре dateTimePicker или MonthPicker

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать поиск по дате в dataGridView с выбором даты пользователем в календаре а не вводом вручную. по другим параметрам сделал все находит. точнее выделяет нужное в datagrid. Если не затруднит с объяснением.

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
            if (main != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < main.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    main.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < main.dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
                        if (main.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                            if (main.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(tbStr.Text))
                            {
                                main.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                                break;
                            }
                }
            }   
        }
```

Выбор критерий поиска происходит в отдельной форме.

[image: Форма поиска такая]

Comment: Искать надо не бегая по DGV, а в источнике данных. У вас есть DataSet в ней таблица, искать нужно в коллекции строк этой таблицы.

Comment: Ok. как это можно  делать? я так понимаю это нужно делать в том же обработчике событий SearchButton_Click.